# Will Ubuntu 12.10 work on Lenovo Ideapad Z585 laptop?

Tags: installation, 12.10

I would like to install Ubuntu 12.10 on my new laptop Lenovo IdeaPad Z585 (A6 4400M 2700 Mhz/15.6"/1366x768/6144Mb/500Gb/DVD-RW/Wi-Fi).

Will the laptop work without problems? All necessary drivers will be installed?

Comment: Generally you're better served with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, because you have Long Term Support, i.e. you will probably get updates later if it won't work already. Anyways, you can always try and install Ubuntu next to your momentaneous OS; if it won't work properly, you can simply delete the partition on your laptop.

Comment: I suggest you try the live CD, 'Try Ubuntu,' and find out. I suspect you will have no problems.

Answer (score 2):

I have your setup and it works perfectly. All the necessary drivers are installed. You only might want to check whether you have an nvidia card. If so, you could take a look at the [bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/) project.